# Using MathJax.typeset(); multiple times

Tags: javascript, mathjax, typeset

I'm having a little problem regarding MathJax v3. I'm changing the values of some HTML elements multiple times and im using `Mathjax.typeset();` to typeset the math components again.

Problem is, that the second time there is an expression in MathJax, `MathJax.typeset()` ist producing a TypeError: t is null.

I tried to reset the enumeration with:

```
MathJax.startup.document.state(0);
MathJax.texReset();
MathJax.typeset();
```

witch only led to a new TypeError: this.parent(...) is null.
This only occurs the second time I call it, and I don't understand what I should do to be able to typeset the document multiple times.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
MathJax.texReset();
MathJax.typesetClear();
MathJax.typeset();
```

The error that you mention is fixed in the next release (see [this PR](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/pull/350)).